# React with SASS - How to work with SASS in React

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

So,  the basic usage of SASS in react is

Install `node-sass` and `import ./mysass.scss` in `index.js` file

I did the same it worked with bootstrap SASS.

I have successfully imported `bootstrap.scss` in `index.js` file

```
import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
```

But, now if I try to import mine it did not work.

Let me give you some information about my SASS files.

- My style.scss file importing other CSS modules by using `@use` instead of `@import` in sass.

  **For example**

  ```
    Using -> `@use 'sections/navbar';`
    Instead of  -> `@import 'sections/navbar';`
  ```
- I am also using `@use "sass:map";`

Does this `@use` create the problem?

I have checked the `bootstrap.scss` file and they are using `@import`.

Comment: So the issue is you aren't able to import other scss files to your root scss files using `@use`. Right ? Is it working using `@import` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried @import and it worked but the problem is then how can I use sass:map?

Comment: Any errors it is throwing?

Comment: It gives me error ->  https://prnt.sc/1d1nvn2

Comment: Have you checked https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/issues/6431

Comment: no but let me try it real quick

Comment: Thank you soo much it worked successfully. I have invested an hour just to solve that.

Comment: I request you to add this as an Answer.

Comment: Have added as an Answer. Glad to know it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this issue on Github: [Link](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/issues/6431#issuecomment-680157712). Solution posted by user **asyncLiz**.

> That error is typically seen when using the `node-sass` implementation, which does not support Sass modules and is not supported by MDC. You'll need to use the Dart sass implementation.

> Luckily it's an easy replacement when using sass-loader. Run `npm uninstall node-sass && npm install sass`. `sass-loader` will automatically use the new implementation.

> If it does not, check your webpack.config.js in case you're manually specifying the implementation in your sass-loader options. If you are, change `implementation: require('node-sass')` to `implementation: require('sass')`.